# Fatal error: Class 'Queldorei_ShopperSettings_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Field_Font' on magento

Tags: php, magento, admin

Fatal error: Class 'Queldorei_ShopperSettings_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Field_Font' not found in D:\wamp\www\WORK\WholesaleStore\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 590

how to solve this problem... on magento..?

thanks for help in advance for helping me..

Comment: You are calling one class that are not defined.Queldorei_ShopperSettings_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Field_Font.check this class exists.

Comment: yup you are right there was missing that file but i want to solve this problem how can i solve this problem.?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class in the following folder structure:
ShopperSettings->Bock->Adminhtml->System->Config->Form->Field->Font.php. Hopes that's help you.